# $\int_c {{e^Z+Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ$

Tags: complex-analysis

find

$\int_c {{e^Z+Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ$

such that $c$ is a the circle $|Z|=4$

my try

$\int_c {{e^Z+Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ=\int_c {{e^Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ+\int_c {{Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ$

- $\int_c {{e^Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ$

let $f(Z)= e^Z$

$f'(Z)=e^Z$

$\int_c {{e^Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ=2\pi i f'(\pi)$

$=2\pi i e^{\pi}$

and for

- $\int_c {{Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ$

let $f(Z)=Z \sinh Z$

$f'(Z)=\sinh Z +Z \cosh Z$

$\int_c {{Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ=2 \pi i f'(\pi)$

$=2\pi i (\sinh \pi + \pi \cosh \pi )$

so

$\int_c {{e^Z+Z \sinh Z}\over {(Z- \pi)}^2} dZ=2\pi i (e^{\pi}+\sinh \pi +\pi \cosh \pi)$

true?

I saw in a book the finally answer is $-2\pi i (1+\pi i)$ but I can't got this answer :( what's the wrong?

Comment: $-2\pi i (1+\pi i)$ would be the integral of $\frac{e^z + z \sinh(z)}{(z- \pi i)^2}$

Comment: aha, ok thank you, is that's mean my answer is true ?